# How can I show the raw json string in wordpress api

Tags: wordpress, api, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

On my custom wordpress api endpoint I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

How can I debug that? I would like to see the actual json string that can not be parsed. Is that possible some how?

Here is my callback function:

```php
function get_price_callback() {

    $resp = get_price('25-05-2021','Depoistum');
    $val = htmlspecialchars($resp);
        
    $type = htmlspecialchars( $_GET["type"] );
    return rest_ensure_response([$date]);
    }

get_price('25-05-2021','Depoistum') // will return 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use wordpress `wp_send_json_success` and `wp_send_json_error` functions. So your callback function would be somthing like this:

```php
function get_price_callback(){

    $resp = get_price('25-05-2021','Depoistum');

    $val = htmlspecialchars($resp); // You could also use wordpress "esc_html" function for sanitization instead! 
        
    $type = esc_html( $_GET["type"] ); // or sanitize_text_field() function

    $data = array($val, $type);
  
    wp_send_json_success($date); 

   // or you could send it via  "wp_send_json_error", if you need to!
}
```

You could read more about these two functions on the documentation page.

> [WordPress `wp_send_json_success` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json_success/)
> [WordPress `wp_send_json_error` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json_error/)

Comment: Replacing the return statement with: wp_send_json_error($date); makes no difference.

Comment: Like i said, `wp_send_json_success` is the wordpressish way of sending your data in json format. If you can't get it to work, probably there is a bug somewhere in your code on the front end that you didn't show us.